# rollback conflict resolving in TFS

Tags: tfs

I wrote a c# project. 
This project was checked in to TFS a year ago with old code . It was checked it by someone else (not me), so my project wasn't mapped to TFS source control. 
Yesterday i mapped this project to my local project folder (where the new code is located), and ecsidently did Get Latest, causing conflicts in code. 
I resolved the conflicts by choosing "overwrite local file...". 
But now my local code is the "old" code that was checked in a year ago. 
How can i get back the last code i had before mapping to the Source Control ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have overwritten your local files, they are effectively overwritten. Can't see how you can revert back to a version before your activity, unless you have a local copy somewhere else. Not good news I am afraid.